# DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get the text of some of my DDL items to be displayed in a label, but I cannot. I've used the property DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text, but according to some Google results, it doesn't work hardly ever.

When I try to get values of items, I haven't any problem.

**Is there any alternative to get the DDL items text?**

Comment: Could you please post your code? Your dropdownlist. How you add your data there? etc. Thanks

Comment: And what does mean "it doesn't work". Do you get an exception? Or is it empty? Or happens?

Comment: Used correctly, `DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text` should perfeclty work. Please post your code and tell us what is not working specifically (getting an error, wrong text, empty text, etc?)

Comment: Post the code of your dropdownlist. I just used a ddl in c# and asp.net and it worked perfectly.

Comment: In my case, I am using a LinqDataSource that provides some items which have empty values. If only provides items with full values, there's no problem. I cannot understand this. The code is the following: (next comment)

Comment: `<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource2" runat="server" ContextTypeName="palabras" EntityTypeName="" Select="new (localidad, db)" TableName="pueblod"></asp:LinqDataSource>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource2" DataTextField="localidad" DataValueField="basededatos" Height="30px" Width="264px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged1" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True">               
                </asp:DropDownList>`

Comment: The DropDownList is under a UpdatePanel and also, asigned to this as a Trigger (AsyincPostBackTrigger).

Comment: where is your <asp:label> control? is it inside UpdatePanel? If not, put it under UpdatePanel, too.

Comment: @w3hunter, the <asp:Label> is under the UpdatePanel. But the problem only happens if I don't filter LinqDataSource items with empty values. I cannot filter them, I need them. In addition, the DDL reselects the 1st item when I select another without values. I cannot understand this.

Comment: btw, where are you assigning value to Label? in code behind?

Answer (score 0):

**Visual Studios**

This will assign your label the text of the selected item.

```
protected void ddldetails_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   txtname.Text = ddldetails.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

**ASP.NET**

Creating the DDL and the Label in ASP.NET. Obviously not everything, just where I wrote the ASP.NET code to get the values and whatnot.

```
... //Other stuff

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddldetails" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
        onselectedindexchanged="ddldetails_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="0">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Asp.net</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">C#.NET</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="3">VB.NET</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Label ID="txtname" runat="server">
</asp:Label>
...
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but my problem happens because it's assigned to a LinqDataSource that provides some items with empty values. I've exposed the code in the node of comments of the question.

Comment: I would go through the ones with empty values and fill them, or just get rid of them. I don't do much work with LINQDataSources....sorry :/

Comment: I've tried to fix the problem using a SQLDataSource, but the problem continues. My problem is that I can only display the text of items with values, but once I have selected one of them and I want to select another without value, it's displayed the text of the 1st item, that has no value.

Comment: I would get rid of those ones with empty values.

Comment: I cannot get tid of them because I need to check if the table exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find dropdown control first....

```
DropDownList ddlStatus = default(DropDownList);
ddlStatus = (DropDownList)FindControl("DropDownList1"); //DropDownList1 is id of your DropDownList
string ddlValue=ddlStatus.SelectedItem.Text;
```